# cant style a button in chrome extension page

Tags: css, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm building a chrome extension, I have options page but seems like Chrome overriding button default style so I cant style a button on `:hover` nor on `:focus`.

Does chrome extension on options pages disable some CSS?  especially options page, since my popup page isn't affected.

My CSS :

```
.button.is-primary {
    background-color: #7957d5;
    border-color: transparent;
    color: white;
}
```

But the button looks same on options page.

Comment: 1) Try adding `"chrome_style":false` as shown in the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest), 2) Try using [!important](https://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/).

Comment: @wOxxOm Oh thanks, never know that on docs!. you can answer the question, `chrome_style: false` solved my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Try adding "chrome_style":false as shown in the documentation, 
2) Try using !important. –

@wOxxOm comment solve my problem.